# How to call more than one url from one button in jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to call two urls through a button in jQuery. For example, I want to add the commented one as well. How shall I represent them?

```
$.ajax({
        //    url: 'ajax/releaseBackEnd.php',
            url: 'batch/2-release-tmp.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: {"fId":"abc"},
            dataType: 'xml',
            error: function(){
                alert('Error loading XML document');
            },
            success: function(data){        
                //check error
                alert("success");
                var $error=$(data).find('error').text();
                if($error!="0")
                {
                    messageBox("Error",$error);
                    return;
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make an AJAX request to 2 URLs simultaneously/in the same call, you'll need to call them separately as 2 different [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls.

You could make it a function for example:

```
function doAJAX(url) {
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data: {"fId":"abc"},
      dataType: 'xml',
      error: function(){
          alert('Error loading XML document');
      },
      success: function(data){        
          //check error
          alert("success");
          var $error=$(data).find('error').text();
          if($error!="0")
          {
              messageBox("Error",$error);
          }
      }
  });
}
doAJAX('ajax/releaseBackEnd.php');
doAJAX('batch/2-release-tmp.php');
```

Comment: Dang, once again, faster than me :(